# Tensor field without defining manifolds

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, manifolds, tensors

I'm currently learning tensors. I've learnt scalar and vector fields in 2-D or 3-D. But when I looked at the definition of tensor field, they usually mentioned associating a point on a manifold with a tensor. I kind of know how this works out. But can we discuss the property of tensor fields only on 2-D or 3-D points? Will their property still be maintained?

I'm also curious about how to take derivative of tensor fields, and how tensor fields are usually applied in differential geometry. Thanks!

Comment: Tensors at a point makes sense. It's basically an application of linear algebra, using different notation. It gets a lot more interesting once you have tensors defined over a space, though. Then it's called tensor calculus. There are a couple of playlists that I've enjoyed. [This one](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlXfTHzgMRULkodlIEqfgTS-H1AY_bNtq) is a series of filmed lectures on tensor calculus, while [this](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJHszsWbB6hrkmmq57lX8BV-o-YIOFsiG) and then [this](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLJHszsWbB6hpk5h8lSfBkVrpjsqvUGTCx) is an alternative.

Comment: @Arthur By "over a space", do you mean higher dimensions? I thought a 2-D or 3-D point is also in a space.

Comment: It's possible to speak of tensor fields in (open subsets of) the plane or space, yes, but doing so is literally equivalent to working on a manifold of dimension two or three. Once we start to take derivatives, we need the additional structure of a _connection_ (a way of axiomizing derivatives), but again if we work locally there's no difference between manifolds and the plane or space.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang What is "a connection" you are referring to? Is there any source you would recommend if I just want to work locally on the plane or space?

Comment: @Kylinny A connection is what you need on general manifolds to differentiate anything more complicated than a scalar function, such as vector fields. And by "over a space", I mean in _any_ dimension. 2-D and 3-D being the most common concrete examples that people use, because those we can actually visualize (and 1-D is a bit boring). Euclidean space is very possible, but to see the full power of tensor calculus, you need to see it in action on non-flat spaces, so manifolds it is (in concrete examples it's most commonly the sphere, because again, it's what we can most easily visualize).

Answer (score 2):

A tensor is a multilinear function on a vector space $V$. A tensor field is defined as follows: Start with a smooth parametrized family of vector spaces. A tensor field is simply a smoothly varying assignment to each parameter a tensor on the corresponding vector space. The parameter space can be anything you want. The most common setting in differential geometry is the tangent bundle, where the parameter space is comprised of points in a manifold and the vector space associated to each point is the tangent space at that point. So a tensor field would be a tensor on each tangent space in the manifold that depends smoothly on the point in the manifold.

If you use the vector space $V$ itself as the manifold, then a tensor field is simply a smooth map from each vector in $V$ to a tensor on $V$. If you fix a basis of $V$, then you get a basis of the corresponding tensor space and therefore, the tensor field can be written as an array of scalar functions on $V$. You can then differentiate the tensor field with respect to the coordinates on $V$. This kind of differentiation is called a "flat connection".

If $V$ is either $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $\mathbb{R}^3$, then you get the 2D and 3D tensor fields you're mentioning.

If the parameter space is a non-flat manifold, such as a sphere, then differentiation of a tensor field becomes a bit more involved, requiring the concept of what's known as a connection or a covariant derivative.

Comment: I just realized I might misunderstand something. Do you mean a tensor field assign a vector space to a tensor? I thought tensor fields, just like vector fields and scalar fields assign points in a space but not vector spaces.

Comment: 1) A tensor is a multilinear function whose domain is a vector space. 2) A tensor field over a space assigns to each point in the space a tensor.